# (GO) Как убрать параметр Exp, при выводе массива?

Tags: mysql, golang

```
type Rating struct {
    ID uint32 `json:"id"`
    Lvl uint32 `json:"lvl"`
    Exp uint32 `json:"exp"`
}

var users []Rating
...
users = append(users, Rating{ID: p.ID, Lvl: p.Lvl})
...
return users;
```

При выводе, будет заметен exp, что нужно сделать, чтобы он не входил в запрос. Убирать его нельзя, поскольку понадобится в другом хендлере.

Comment: Вопрос ведь о взаимодействии с БД? Через какую-то orm-библиотеку планируете взаимодействовать? Обычно есть специфичные для конкретной orm теги для структур, позволяющие игнорировать те или иные поля... Либо соглашение об именовании.

Comment: "database/sql"                  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"